# How to track a file is uploaded successfully or not in file upload control using c#?

Tags: c#, file-upload

How to track a file is uploaded successfully or not in file upload control using c# ? so that we can give some custom message?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean the ASP.NET FileUpload control? In that case you can just check the [FileUpload.HasFile Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile.aspx). If this is true, you have your file. After that, of course, you need to save the file to the filestore or database, but you can check for exceptions in the save method and if you are really paranoid use [System.IO.File.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) to veryify it is there (presuming you save it to filestore).

Comment: Thanks, I think System.IO.File.Exists() may be use full